# How to determine when a float passes an integer boundary

Tags: c++, floating-point

So I have a float value that get's incremented by some fractional value. I need a quick and easy way to determine whenever an integer boundary is crossed - 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 etc.

I swear there was a nice little gem kicking around years ago that did this but I can't for the life of me find it!

Anyone got a slick method in mind?

Comment: Hmm, that's going to lead to tears.  Like incrementing by 0.1 and ending up with 0.9999999.  To avoid that you instead increment an integer and compute the floating point value.  Now it is simple.

Comment: Hans is right. Your question has an answer, but you are asking the wrong question.

Comment: (a) What result do you want when a value goes from .75 to 1? From 1 to 1.25? Do both of those “cross” an integer boundary, just the first, just the second, or neither? (b) Are you aware that computing `.1+.1+.1+.1+.1+.1+.1+.1+.1+.1` using `double` (64-bit binary floating-point) arithmetic will not produce 1 but rather 0.99999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875? So sometimes additions will fall before or after integer boundaries when they would not do so if calculated with exact mathematics?

Comment: Can you give bounds for range and precision? Is the float `(f)` bound by: `a <= f <= b` ? Are the increments `(d)` bound by: `|d| < E` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about something as simple as

```
if ( floor(original) != floor(new_value) ) { ... }
```

Comment: Might want to use `floor` instead to properly handle zero crossing.

Comment: @VaughnCato Agreed. Fixed.

Comment: Yeah I think this might just do it. Or casting to an int and then comparing.

Comment: Casting to an in was what I originally had, but as Vaughn correctly pointed out, that doesn't catch crossing zero.